# How do I fill in the Internet Server Certificate request form in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, hostheaders

I'm requesting my first SSL certificate for one of a pair of test servers (2008 R2, IIS7).  Our CA is not part of AD so I've worked out that I need to do the '[request an Internet certificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732906(WS.10).aspx)'.  That link isn't very helpful, though, because it doesn't tell you what to put in the boxes.  I'm pretty sure I'm okay with everything except the 'Common name' box.  I think I need to put the server name in here but I'm not sure.

Normally, I use host-headers with my sites so that my networking guys can provide me with load-balancing or, at least, fail-over across a pair of servers.  Can I do that, here, and if so, do I fill in the host-header name or the server name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is complicated and I don't want to get it wrong, in case anyone else reads this.  Suffice to say, I'm looking at using subjectAltName on the certificate request so that people who use the host-header address will still get to the site without getting a certificate warning.